# URL redirection for promos link throws "The resource cannot be found" page

Tags: bug, status-completed, broken-link, redirection, promotions

In some of the [posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A%22*stackexchange.com%2Fpromos%22), the link for the promotion page is pointing to https://stackexchange.com/promos. This was obsolete and it automatically redirect to https://contests.stackoverflow.com/promos, but that is throwing "The resource cannot be found."

So the link https://stackexchange.com/promos can be redirect to https://contests.stackoverflow.com (the valid one) instead of https://contests.stackoverflow.com/promos.

Comment: Since it cause broken links, I'd consider this a bug. Let's hope they fix it soon.